# Uncaught ReferenceError while calling function from another module

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript modules i.e database.js and common.js and one main module i.e input_data.js.
`database.js`:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-firestore-lite.js";
import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // config here
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

const db = getFirestore(app);

let usersListTmp = [];

async function getUsersListFromDB() {

    if (usersListTmp.length == 0) { // Getting error here!
        await getDocs(collection(db, "users")).then((usersSnapshot) => {
            usersSnapshot.forEach((value) => {
                usersListTmp.push(value.data());
            });
        });
    }
    return usersListTmp;
}

export {
    getUsersListFromDB
}
```

`common.js`

```
import { getUsersListFromDB } from "../database/database.js";

let usersList = await getUsersListFromDB(); // here is the function call
console.log(usersList);

function getUsersList() {
    return usersList;
}

function setUsersList(list) {
    usersList = list;
}

export {
    getUsersList,
    setUsersList
}
```

`input_data.js`

```
import { registerUser, getUsersListFromDB } from "../database/database.js";
import { getUsersList } from "../js/common.js"

let usersList = getUsersList(); // here is the initial function call
```

console.log(usersList);

I'm calling `getUsersListFromDB()` from common.js file and getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'usersListTmp' before initialization
```

I want this variable `usersListTmp` to be only accessed within current module. After changing code a bit now I'm getting same error for `firebaseConfig`, `app`, `auth` and `db`.

EDIT:
For some reason, none of my global variables are being initialized. On function call only the function is running without initializing global variables.

Comment: The ES6 module code itself is fine, but it seems to be transpiled incorrectly. How exactly are you transpiling the code? Apparently you’re transpiling it into a CommonJS module somehow.

Comment: I don't understand. I just want to call the function from the common.js file.

Comment: See the JS docs about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init. I think you have to export the `usersListTmp` variable too so that the function to be exported can use it on the fly.

Comment: This sounds like you've met the temporal dead zone from a circular module dependency. Your *database.js* somehow appears to import *common.js*, is that correct? Please show us the the entire `import` and `export` declarations of all the involved modules.

Comment: @Bergi I hava updated the code and also added the file from which im calling function initially

Comment: Hm, that should really work, are you sure there are no other imports in *database.js*?

Comment: I don't know why but when I change the order of import statements in `input_data.js` it works fine.